# convert curl to coldfusion cfhttp

Tags: curl, coldfusion, http-status-code-406

I have a curl call that works like a charm:

`curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H "X-ApiVersion: 1.0" -H  "X-AccessToken: [api-token]" -d '[xml]' https://www.API.com`

I've tried to convert it to coldfusion, but the server kicks back a 406 error on me. I've tried throwing everything I can think of at this problem, but can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated! Here's the CF:

```
<cfhttp url="#APIURL#" method="POST" result="activity">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-AccessToken" value="#accesstoken#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-ApiVersion" value="1.0" />   
    <cfhttpparam type="body" encoded="false" value="#trim(request.xml)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: Is it worth mentioning the `url` value is lacking a closing pound sign?

Comment: ha, nice catch! but no, that was just a quick hack to hide the real url and token.

Comment: I do not see anything obviously wrong. Try some low tech debugging. Create a test page on your CF server that dumps the request [`GetHTTPRequestData()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/GetHttpRequestData). Call that page from both curl and cfhttp and see what is different about the requests.

Comment: For grins, trying adding an "Accept" header to cfhttp. I saw somewhere that curl may add an Accept: */*  header. Based on the error code, that might be relevant here. If not, your best bet is to look at the raw request dumps (as suggested above) and see what is different.

Comment: Crud... I forgot SO interprets asterisk as italics. That should have read:  `Accept: */*`.

Comment: Try `<cfhttpparam type="XML" value="#trim(request.xml)#">` instead of `<cfhttpparam type="body" encoded="false" value="#trim(request.xml)#" />`

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks to Leigh!  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="\*/\*"> did the trick. Thanks to all that answered!

Answer (score 3):

(From the comments)

For grins, trying adding an "Accept" header to the cfhttp call. I saw somewhere that curl may add an accept all header by default: `Accept: */*`. Based on the [406 error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error), that might be relevant here.

> **406 Not Acceptable**
>   The requested resource is only capable of generating content not acceptable according to the Accept headers sent
>   in the request.

If not, your best bet is to look at the raw request dumps ([as suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463551/convert-curl-to-coldfusion-cfhttp#comment50895215_31463551)) and see what is different.

**Update:**

CraigL confirmed in the comments that adding an "Accept" all header resolved the issue. Posting the full code here so the solution is more visible:

```
<cfhttp url="#APIURL#" method="POST" result="activity">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-AccessToken" value="#accesstoken#" />
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-ApiVersion" value="1.0" />   
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="*/*"> 
    <cfhttpparam type="body" encoded="false" value="#trim(request.xml)#" />
</cfhttp>
```